# Brézis Exercise 3.18

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, lp-spaces, weak-convergence, weak-lp-spaces

For every integer $n \geq 1$ let
$$e^n=(0,0,\dots,\underset{(n)}{1},0,\dots).$$

1. Prove that $e^n \underset{n \rightarrow \infty}{\rightharpoonup} 0$ in $\ell^p$ weakly $\sigma(\ell^p,\ell^{p'})$ with $1 < p \leq \infty$.

**My attempt:** For $1<p<\infty$ and $f \in (\ell^p)'$, there exists $g=(g_1,g_2,\dots) \in \ell^{p'}$ such that
$$\langle f, x \rangle_{(\ell^p)',\ell^p}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}g_n x_n \hbox{ for all } x=(x_1,x_2,\dots) \in \ell^p.$$
So that,
$$\langle f, e^n \rangle_{(\ell^p)',\ell^p}=g_n. \tag{*}$$

Since $g \in \ell^{p'}$, then $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|g_n|^{p'}<\infty$ which implies that $|g_n|^{p'} \rightarrow 0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty.$ Hence, $|g_n|\rightarrow 0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$. Therefore, from $(*)$ we obtain that
$$\langle f, e^n \rangle_{(\ell^p)',\ell^p} \rightarrow 0 \hbox{ as } n \rightarrow \infty.$$
Is this correct?

**My question:** How to prove that $e^n \underset{n \rightarrow \infty}{\rightharpoonup} 0$ in $\ell^\infty$ weakly $\sigma(\ell^\infty,(\ell^{\infty})')$?

Comment: first question: correct.

Comment: second: see duplicate